# Type instance syntax

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, haskell

I have already learned haskell from http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters, but it doesn't cover the type instance syntax, like this:

```
data Auctioning
instance Scripts.ValidatorTypes Auctioning where
    type instance RedeemerType Auctioning = AuctionAction
    type instance DatumType Auctioning = AuctionDatum
```

I known the first line is declared the Auctioning date type, the second line is make Auctioning instance of ValidatorTypes, but what does type instance means? I can't find this syntax from haskell.

Answer (score 3):

This code is implementing the `ValidatorTypes` ["Typeclass"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) for the `Auctioning` datatype.

Typeclasses are Haskell's way of handling polymorphism, like abstract classes in an OO language. In this case, the `ValidatorTypes` typeclass has two associated types, `RedeemerType` and `DatumType`, that need to be defined for our validator. [Here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/plutus-ledger/src/Ledger/Typed/Scripts/Validators.hs#L45) is the definition of that typeclass.

Check out the "Typeclasses 102" section in the [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) tutorial (scroll down) to learn more.